# SSRS Shared Data Source username and password "save credentials" changed to "Do not use credentials" automatically

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am generating a SSRS report for that, I have created a Shared Data Source for my project, for the connection string I am passing username and password and did the checkmark for "Save Credentials" and from my Dataset I executed my query everything work fine. When I deployed to server it was throwing me with error password wrong. When I downloaded the version from TFS it automatically moved to "Do not use credentials". Can you please tell me if I am missing something.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbxSK.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that username and password are deployed with the shared datasource, neither can they be downloaded. But:

Shared datasources usually are deployed only once. The default settings prevent existing shared datasources to be overwitten when deploying report projects. So, once the shared datasource is deployed and exists on the server, you can edit the deployed shared datasource (in the Report Server Portal) and specify the credentials there. Of course, this is neccessary only once.